# Python download every image Vbulletin

Tags: python, download

I want to download every image in the thread of a particular forum thread of a message board I happen to frequent (project1999.org).  This is not homework.  I am very bad at programming, I use linux.  I got stuck can anyone help?  I would very much appreciate it.

The thread in question is about cat images lol.  Here it is: http://www.project1999.org/forums/showthread.php?t=37779

I'm using BeautifulSoup seems good no?

HELP please :{

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def DownloadImagesVB(startUrl, saveDirectory):
    startPage = 1
    while True:
        url = startUrl + "&p=" + str(startPage)
        print url
        startPage += 1
        urllib2.urlopen(startUrl)

if __name__=="__main__":
    url = "http://www.project1999.org/forums/showthread.php?t=37779"
    path = "/home/r00t/cats"
    DownloadImagesVB(url, path)
```

Comment: Any reason you want to spend time writing code to do this, when you could just a web browser extension or use `wget` or `curl` or HTTrack to do it?

Comment: what browser extension I would ask in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import lxml.html

# here's some ugly code I've glued together from my IPython %history:
#
# I know it's crap, It's about ~10mins from start to finish, one
# alternative would be to simply generate <img src=""> links for each of
# the images and then rely on Firefox/Chrome to save the whole page...
# this would make prettier file names, and I get the impression this 
# is a one-off script...
# --Stuart




def find_images(url):

    root=lxml.html.parse(url).getroot()
    root.make_links_absolute()
    imgs = []
    for i in root.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "post_message")]//img'):
        src = i.attrib.get('src','')
        if 'project1999' not in src:
            imgs.append(i.attrib.get('src',''))
    return imgs



def main():
    nums=[x+1 for x in range(52)]
    urls=['http://www.project1999.org/forums/showthread.php?s=6be291d52837a8ab512858dde188569c&t=37779&page=%d' %num for num in nums]

    todownload = []
    for url in urls:
        for img in find_images(url):
            todownload.append(img)


    todownload = list(set(todownload)) #remove duplicates

    print "downloading %d images" % len(todownload)

    # save all the images without extensions.. (lazy)
    for count, i in enumerate(todownload):
        try:
            print "%d downloading %s" % (count, i)
            open('imgs/%d' % count, 'w').write(requests.get(i).content)
        except:
            print "couldn't download %s" %i



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*It's currently chuggin along...*

```
...
92 downloading http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o60/mven42/f1b88059.jpg
93 downloading https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cXKgVQVodRI/TmvYln0uj6I/AAAAAAAAO1k/H4sx5srDX6Q/Cat-Gifs-Shared-by-Gplus-Jay-Puri_62.gif
94 downloading http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ls8pbds3sL1qfjjglo1_400.gif
95 downloading http://i43.tinypic.com/169goet.gif
96 downloading http://i.imgur.com/5qbXk.gif
97 downloading http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/547/hahajkg.jpg
98 downloading http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/6856/catmb.jpg
99 downloading http://i.imgur.com/PDiEa.gif
100 downloading http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnybntpx2o1qlue6co1_100.gif
101 downloading http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-G6LADm3UlmE/TfeDHI9iQNI/AAAAAAAAAsw/sZ0R6wcdZgc/s640/cat+vs+dog+002.jpg
102 downloading http://i1179.photobucket.com/albums/x393/Drogula/gifs/1312351009032.gif
103 downloading http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lltfczZDdA1qkbyimo1_500.gif
104 downloading http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg860/scaled.php?tn=0&server=860&filename=snajs.jpg&xsize=640&ysize=640
105 downloading http://i357.photobucket.com/albums/oo12/azen32/2011-11-0919-25-15998.jpg
106 downloading http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/2678/caturday35.png
107 downloading http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/funny-pictures-cat-gravity-wins.jpg
108 downloading http://s3-ak.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/web05/2011/12/7/17/anigif_enhanced-buzz-2926-1323297290-29.gif
109 downloading http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/315738_2385906201789_1074780041_32733561_1154490844_n.jpg
```

[here's a list of the 330 images](http://sente.cc/c/5fg8/images.txt)